# 404 on Openshift URL, URL fine on dev

Tags: url, openshift

I have a website that I am developing locally and pushing to RH Openshift with a PHP-5.4 and MySQL cartridge.

Most URL's work, but I am having an issue with some page URL's being recognised locally, but returning a 404 on Openshift.

Example: on development the following URL works: local.development.local/public/reset.php but visiting the Openshift url: example.rhcloud.com/public/reset.php returns a 404. However, example.rhcloud.com/reset.php works, even though reset.php is within the public folder directory.

The folder structure is the exact same on development as it is within Openshift repo folder.

Is there a specific setting I need to set in my Openshift environment to get it to recognize the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the directory structure I had given my website. Since I had placed the majority of my code within a folder named public, Openshift was using that as the DocumentRoot. This wasn't my required functionality, so I renamed the folder to app, updated my URL's and this resolved the issue. Blog post giving the Openshift DocumentRoot logic can be found here: https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-online-march-2014-release-blog/